# How to compare encoding string in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am newbie in ruby and have really small issue. I have following log string in which we can see there is encoding string here. For example http://testsap.com this is the part of the log message but in encoding form.

Now I want to compare whether this contains http://testsap.com or not using ruby.

```
Action=SendMessage&Version=2012-11-05&QueueUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4566%2F000000000000%2Faccounts-processor&MessageBody=%7B%22postBody%22%3A%22mock+Invitation+message%22%2C%22postUrl%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Ftestsap.com%22%7D
```

Can someone help to do that?
Note: I can not decode log string. only that I can do this I can encode/decode (http://testsap.com) string.

Comment: Why can't you decode the string? In any case, characters are characters--you can compare the encoded string the same way as any other.

Comment: can you give an example for this?

Comment: @StillLearning you can check if it contains `http%3A%2F%2Ftestsap.com`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the string is [CGI/HTML form encoded](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.1). Therefore you could do the following:

```
require "cgi"

string = "Action=SendMessage&Version=2012-11-05&QueueUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4566%2F000000000000%2Faccounts-processor&MessageBody=%7B%22postBody%22%3A%22mock+Invitation+message%22%2C%22postUrl%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Ftestsap.com%22%7D"
pattern = "http://testsap.com"

string.include?(CGI.escape(pattern))
# or
CGI.unescape(string).include?(pattern)
```